# Linq and trying to join on a let statement results

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do use linq in a way to avoid doing a foreach over DataRows in a DataSet:

```
var results = from dataRow in DataRows
              let MoreData = func(dataRow.ID)
              join moreDataRow in MoreData on dataRow.ID2 = moreDataRow.ID2
              select new
              {
                  ID1 = dataRow.ID,
                  ID2 = dataRow.ID2,
                  ID3 = dataRow2.ID3
              };
```

I'd like to accomplish something like the above, but linq cannot use the MoreData as part of the join statement.  If I'm unable to do that I may result to just doing a foreach on DataRows and going from there.

Is there a linqy way to join on data that won't be available until iterating over an element and then performing a join from the original data to the newly generated data as above?

Comment: What is the type of MoreData?

Comment: I believe you can either join on the output of your func directly like: func(dataRow.Id).Join(....) or by wrapping it up (from ... let MoreData = func(dataRow.ID) select MoreData).Join(...) edit, this comment makes no sense please ignore and read the mighty skeet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `join` clause has to take a complete collection - not something which depends on the current row. You can use multiple `from` statements though:

```
var results = from dataRow in DataRows
              from moreDataRow in func(dataRow.ID)
              where dataRow.ID2 == moreDataRow.ID2
              select new
              {
                  ID1 = dataRow.ID,
                  ID2 = dataRow.ID2,
                  ID3 = dataRow2.ID3
              };
```

Comment: I suppose that does make sense.  It seemed reasonable that it might let me use that temporary collection to join on.